# Is there standard notation for adjustments to functions?

Tags: functions, notation

In set theory, we can formalize a function $f:A\to B$ as a set $f_{set}$ of tuples $(x,y)$, where $f(x)=y$ iff $(x,y)\in f_{set}$. Then we can formalize "the function $g$ that is the same as $f$ except that at $z$ it equals $w$" as $g_{set}=(f_{set}\setminus \{(z,x) | x\in B \})\cup \{(z,w)\}$. But obviously this notation is kind of ugly and complex compared to what it's trying to define. Also it is undesirable that it assumes a particular encoding of the function as a set. Is there standard notation for this kind of operation on functions?

Comment: $g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&x\ne z\\w&x=z\end{cases}$?

Comment: Right, I was hoping for something more succinct